# Passenger loads fastthread gem from system instead of bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, bundler

I'm getting this error:

*** Exception Gem::LoadError in PhusionPassenger::Railz::ApplicationSpawner (You have already activated fastthread 1.0.1, but your Gemfile requires fastthread 1.0.7. Consider using bundle exec.) (process 27484)

in production.  I have a feeling this is because Passenger is loading the fastthread from the system gems which is version 1.0.1.  Then when it boots the app, the app tries to load fastthread version 1.0.7 (as required by my app), so there's a conflict.

Is there a way to tell Passenger to load its gems from my bundle instead of system?

Answer (score 1):

Which version of passenger are you running? The newer versions should respect your Gemfile.